# Display bytes read in a Spark+Parquet program

Tags: apache-spark, query-optimization, parquet

I'm trying to optimise both some Spark queries and a Parquet schema, by taking advantage of things like partitions and pushdown. My understanding is that these techniques allow large portions of the Parquet files to be skipped.

Is there a way to display the number of bytes that was read by Spark versus the total size of the Parquet files? And additionally, the number of read operations? (I'm using S3, so I'd like to minimise the number of read operations due to the overhead of the S3 API calls.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using apache spark (and not EMR's private variant), the S3A connector collects a [lot of stats](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-tools/hadoop-aws/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3a/Statistic.java#L33), including things like: bytes discarded when closing connections, #of HEAD requests, throttled operations, etc

But: its not really collected in spark, and because a single instance of the filesystem class for each s3 bucket (hence statistics) is used per worker, even once you do work out how to collect them they tend to over-estimate the amount of effort. There's opportunities to improve things there, but it'd take a lot of work. All you currently get is the per-thread bytes read, bytes written statistics, which can actually under-report bytes written, if the HTTP requests to upload data is done in a background thread.

You can enable `org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AStorageStatistics` to log at debug and then the logs of each spark worker will actually track those operations as they happen, but its very noisy. Primarily useful when trying to debug things or doing low-level performance optimisation of something like the Parquet reader itself.

No idea about EMR I'm afraid —not my code.

Comment: I'm using s3a and that sounds exactly what I'm looking for, but I'm using pyspark and can't work out how to set the log4j logging properties. I'll post that in a separate SO question.

Comment: oh, also: on the more recent (2.8+?) versions of Hadoop, if you can get an instance of the S3AFileSystem class in a process and call toString() on it, you get a dump of all the current values